# Trying to add a navigation bar in my footer which is in my layout page(which my master page)

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, uinavigationbar

Trying to add a navigation bar in my footer which is in my layout page(which my master page, all the pages will inherit the footer).I want to make my icon color for the active page to red but i dont want to add footer to all the pages.Is there to do it from the layout page???

here is the code i have written in my layout page, when i go to another page, the home1 icon remains red.... I am trying to make the current page icon red

```
<footer class="footer">
    <!-- Just an image -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light" id="myDIV">
        <a class="navbar-brand " href="/home1">
            <i class="mynav fas fa-home active"></i>
        </a>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/home2">
            <i class="mynav fas fa-shopping-basket"></i>
        </a>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/home3">
            <i class="mynav fas fa-cog"></i>
        </a>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/home4">
            <i class="mynav fas fa-star"></i>
        </a>
    </nav>
</footer>
```

//JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var header = document.getElementById("myDIV");
var btns = header.getElementsByClassName("mynav");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
    btns[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
        var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
        if (current.length > 0) {
            current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
        this.className += " active";
    });
}
```

//CSS

```
 .mynav .active {
 color: black;
 }

 .active, .mynav:hover {
 color: #dc3545;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could loop through all the anchors in the footer and compare their `href` with the path of the current page and add the class on a true result.

```
const anchors = document.querySelectorAll('#myDIV a');
const currentPage = window.location.pathname;

Array.prototype.forEach.call(anchors, (a) => {
  if (a.getAttribute('href') === currentPage) {
    a.classList.add('active');
  } else {
    a.classList.remove('active');
  }
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't you also remove the `.active` class? Because during this several `a` tags can have this class.

Comment: You are correct, I missed "when I go to another page, the home1 icon remains red". One option would be to omit a _default_ active class on the home page. But, I have updated the example to be explicit.